# Is the map $T: C(X) \to \mathbb{B}(L^2(X,\nu))$ defined by $T(f)=M_f$, where $M_f(g)=fg$, injective?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a compact, Hausdroff space. Suppose that $\nu$ is a probability measure on $X$. Let $T: C(X) \to \mathbb{B}(L^2(X,\nu))$ be defined by $T(f)=M_f$, where $M_f(g)=fg$.

> $M_f$ is well-defined

$\|M_f(g)\|_2^2=\int_X|fg|^2d\nu(x) \le \|f\|_{\infty}^2\int_X|g|^2d\nu(x)=\|f\|_{\infty}^2\|g\|_2^2 \implies \|M_f(g)\|_2 \le \|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_2$. This also shows that $M_f$ is bounded above by $\|f\|_{\infty}$

> $M_f$ is a star homomorphism.

This is because $M_{f_1f_2}(g)=f_1f_2(g)=M_{f_1}(f_2g)=M_{f_1}\circ M_{f_2}(g)$. Also $M_{f}^*=M_{\bar{f}}$. Hence $T(f^*)=T(f)^*$.

I want to see if $T$ is an isometry. It is equivalent to showing that $T$ is injective. Suppose that $T(f)=0$ for some $f \in C(X)$. Then $M_f(g)=0$ for all $g \in L^2(X,\nu)$. Hence, $fg=0$ for all $g \in L^2(X,\nu)$. Suppose that $f$ is not $0$. 
Let $E=\{x \in X:f(x) \ne 0$}. Then $E$ is measurable and $0<\nu(E) \le \nu(X)=1$. Since $f\chi_E=0$, we have $f(x)\chi_E(x)=0$ for $x \in E$. Therefore $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in E$. This is a contradiction. Therefore $\nu(E)=0$. Since $f$ is a continuous function, we must have that $f=0$. Thus $T$ is injective. Therefore, $T$ is an isometry.

The proof doesn't depend on the measure $\nu$ except for the fact that $\nu$ is a finite measure. Is this proof alright?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\nu(E)=0$, it seems that we cannot conclude $f=0$ by the continuity of $f$. This goes through if $\nu$ is the standard Euclidean Lebesgue measure.

The following reasoning assumes that if $f\in C(X)$ is such that $f=0$ $\nu$-a.e. then $f=0$ everywhere.

Actually $f$ is $L^{2}(X,\nu)$: We let $M=\max_{x\in X}|f(x)|$, then $\displaystyle\int_{X}|f(x)|^{2}d\nu(x)\leq M^{2}\int_{X}d\nu(x)=M^{2}\nu(X)=M^{2}<\infty$.

So the complex-conjugate $\overline{f}$ is also in $L^{2}$, hence $M_{f}(\overline{f})=0$, in particular, $|f|^{2}=f\cdot\overline{f}=0$, hence $f=0$.

**If $\nu$ is such that $\nu(G)>0$ for all nonempty open sets $G$, then our proofs both go through.**

Comment: Do you have a counterexample to why the proof doesn't go through? Also, it is independent of the measure of X. Right?

Comment: I don't have a counterexample right at this moment, but if $\nu$ is a Radon measure, then it should be going through. So the crucial question is that, does the $\nu$ only satisfy $\nu(X)=1$?

Comment: Actually the conditions are on me to impose. So I can impose it on $\nu$.

Comment: Then you may have to assume that $\nu$ is Radon.

Comment: Why does the proof go through if it is Radon measure?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't say it is a matter of Radon. Rather, if $|f(x)|>0$ for some $x$, then we can find some open neighbourhood $G$ of $x$ such that $|f(x)|>0$ for all $x\in G$. Now the question is that, is $\nu(G)>0$? If so, then we get a contradiction.

Comment: Will this proof work when $\nu=\delta_x$ for some $x \in X$?

Comment: Actually from this proof one can see that the only requirement is that $\nu(X)<\infty$, so for the Dirac mass, surely it goes through.

Comment: Let $\nu=\delta_{x_0}$
Define $\phi: L^2(X,\nu) \to C$ by $\phi(f)=f(x_0)$. Then $\phi$ is an isometric $*$-homomorphism.
This means that $L^2(X,\nu)$ is isomorphic to $C$. Hence $B(L^2(X,\nu))$ is isomorphic to $B(C)=C$. In particular the map which sends $S \in B(C)$ to $S(1)$ is an isomorphism. Thus, the map which send $f \in C(X)$ to $\phi (T(f))\phi^{-1}(1)=f(x_0)$ is a map between $C(X)$ and $C$, where $T(f)=M_f$. If $T$ were one-to-one, then the map which sends $f$ to $f(x_0)$ would have been one-to-one, which is not true

Comment: It is a little panic to me. Anyway, why the injectivity of $T$ implies that of $C(X)\rightarrow C$?

Comment: And that $B(C)=C$ is in what sense? The map which sends $S\in B(C)$ to $S(1)$ is an isomorphism, really?

Comment: Atleast the map is one-to-one. That is all we need. Is not it?

Comment: One thing I wish to point out. That $\phi:L^{2}\rightarrow C$ is a topological homeomorphism? If not, how do we then say that $B(L^{2})$ is isomorphic to $B(C)$?

Comment: And one thing here, so apparently $\phi$ is not injective, no? Various little $f$ could take the same value at $x_{0}$.

Comment: But in $L^2(X,\nu)$ we need the function to be zero almost everywhere

Comment: This makes me more and more confused right now. All of a sudden I just wonder if $\phi$ is well defined. To be very precise, $L^{2}$ elements are equivalent classes of functions, if we take different representative $f,g\in[f]=[g]$, then must it be that $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})$?

Comment: ,$f$ and $g$ are almost everywhere equal if they agree on $x_0$

Comment: I am wondering about the other direction: If $f$ and $g$ are almost everywhere equal, then must it be $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})$? If not, then $\phi$ is not even well-defined.

Comment: They have to be at $x_0$. Letting $E=\{x  \in X : f=g\}$. Then if $x_0 \not\in E$, then $\nu(X\E)=1$

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong here, but I have re-checked my reasoning above that one really needs only that $\nu(X)<\infty$, you may re-check and tell me if any flaw is found.

Comment: Let me know if you find a flaw in the counterexample reasoning

Comment: Actually with $E=\{f=g\}$, if $x_{0}\notin E$, then $\nu(X-E)=1$, then what?

Comment: This means that $f$ and $g$ are not equal a.e

Comment: Okay, one question here, why $\phi(T(f))\phi^{-1}(1)=f(x_{0})$? And why injectivity of $T$ implies its injectivity?

Comment: If you look at the way $\phi$ is defined,  I define $\phi^{-1}(z)= f $, where $f(x_0)=z$. There will be several such $f$ but remember they will all be equal $\nu$ almost everywhere. Now if $T$ were injective,I you can see that the map being a composition of three injective maps would be injective

Comment: It seems to me that $\phi(T(\cdot))\phi^{-1}(1)$ is not of the form of composition of three things? Rather, $\phi(T(\cdot))$ is the composition of two things, and the output is a complex number, and this complex number is multiplied with the function $\phi^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: If you name the map which sends $S$ in $B(\mathbb{C})$ to $S(1)$ as $\tilde{\phi}$, then it is a composition of three maps.

Comment: Let $f \in C(X)$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_1)=1$ for $x_0 \ne x_1$. We can do this by Uryhson's Lemma. Then for any $g \in B(L^2(X,\nu))$, I claim that $M_f(g)=0$, $\nu$-a.e. Let $E_g=\{x \in X: f(x)g(x) \ne 0\}$. Then since $x_0 \not \in E_g$, we must have that $\nu(E_g)=0$. Thus $f(x)g(x)=0,\nu$-a.e. But $f \ne 0$.

Comment: Now I almost know what's going wrong with my proof.

Comment: The point is like this: $|f|=0$ $\nu$-a.e. But if $\nu$ is atomic then it does not necessarily that $|f|=0$ everywhere. Because I do Euclidean harmonic analysis, so I always think $\nu$ as the usual Lebesgue measure which is atomless, sorry about that.

Comment: So to have your result to be going through, atomic issue should be taken account.

Comment: If $\nu$ is non-atomic, then my proof would go through?

Comment: Have to re-check again, wait some moment.

Comment: Not sure if atom issue is the key, but I have added the assumption that $\nu(G)>0$ for all nonempty open sets $G$, then our proofs both go through.

Comment: Do you think this is an if and only if statement?

Comment: If the compact set $K$ is such that the interior is nonempty and that $\nu(K)=0$, assume further that the space $X$ can be carried with the Tietze Extension Theorem, then we are ready to get a contradiction.

Comment: I tried the following way: Suppose that there exists $G$ open such that $\nu(G)=0$. Then $G^c$ is closed and hence compact (as $X$ is compact). For $g \in G$, there exists a continuous function $f \in C(X)$ such that $f(g)=1$ and $f|_{G^c}=0$. Then for any $h \in L^2(X, \nu)$, let $E_h=\{x \in X: f(x)h(x) \ne 0\}$. Then $E_h \subset G$ and therefore $\nu(E_h)=0$. Thus $M_f(g)=0, \nu$-a.e but $f \ne 0$. So $T$ is not an isometry.

Comment: Okay that goes through but in some sense the continuous extension assumes some further topological property like $T_{3}$ space or something like that?